# How do I "Copy from" an xml file into PostgreSQL?

Tags: xml, postgresql, copy

Trying to import the contents of either an .xml file or a .txt file into an .xml or char(varying) column in PostgreSQL.
The command is either

```
    COPY wed4(xml) FROM '/h:/test.xml';
```

or

```
    COPY wed4(text) FROM '/h:/test.txt';
```

The new "excuse" for why this does not work is that Postgre can't open the file; "invalid argument," and "**SQL state: XX000.**"

N.B.: I am only trying to use the .txt file because I've been having so much trouble with the .xml file(s), and I (wrongly) thought they might be easier to work with and provide me with some clues to work around. Eventually I will have to use psycopg2 import the content of a lot of .xml files because they don't all have the same internal structure, and so the contents can't be taken apart and inserted into a table easily. As a full set of .xml text, they can however be queried.

I am doing this in pgadmin, not the psql shell.

Yes, I am using PostgreSQL 11 on Windows (and I have no choice in the matter).
Any clues, thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: does it work if you remove the column name? `COPY wed4 FROM '/h:/test.txt';`. Keep in mind that CR/LF will be treated as such ;)

Comment: The structure of xml data is almost certainly incompatible with the copy command, xml consists of a series of tags, and new lines are considered to be new records in COPY. Assuming you are trying to import this into a table with an xml data type, an insert via python, just opening and sending the data would probably be better.

Comment: @JimJones: same error message.

Comment: @Lucas you've got a point. Maybe using the `STDIN` from `COPY` and removing the new lines would be a bit easier: `cat file.xml | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g' | psql dbserver -c "COPY mytable (myxml) FROM STDIN"` <-- Linux :)

Comment: @Lucas: it should work with text, though, shouldn't it (since .txt has no tags)?

Comment: @user8016440 I see. Can you add to your question a `create table` statement and sample of this file you're trying to import?

Comment: @JimJones: I get a "syntax error" with your "cat" line (possibly because I'm not in Linux).

Comment: @user8016440 yes, it only works on a unix console :) I haven't used windows for the last 15 years, so I can't help you with the translation :-D. Add a sample of this file and I will try to import it to my database

Comment: Here's a short version (some of the files run to over 2000 lines of xml):

'INSERT INTO xmldata4(data4) VALUES (
'<hotel666>
 <METADATA>
   <Tags>
  <AcquisitionTime>2018-10-09T10:37:18.5268832+02:00</AcquisitionTime>
  <DetectorState>&lt;CameraState Id=""&gt;
   &lt;ApplyCameraProfile&gt;false&lt;/ApplyCameraProfile&gt;
 &lt;/CameraState&gt;</DetectorState>
  <RoiCenterOffsetX>+000000000000.0000</RoiCenterOffsetX>
  <RoiCenterOffsetY>+000000000000.0000</RoiCenterOffsetY>
   </Tags>
   <DataSchema />
   <AttachmentSchema />
 </METADATA>
</hotel666>'
);'

Comment: @user8016440 I see no error with the file and my `COPY` command worked perfectly: `COPY wed4 FROM '/home/jones/user8016440.xml';`.  Is `'/h:/test.txt'` a valid path and does the postgres user have permissions to read it?

Comment: It is valid, and I have full permission.
I can do imports without problem from csv into tables with more columns, but this just isn't working for some reason.
If I use "Insert into," the best I seem to get is inserting the path string ("/h:/test.xml" or "/h:/test.txt").

Comment: @user8016440 really strange... I just can't see how it could go wrong. I'll add my short script to an answer and you can take a look.. maybe it will give you a hint where to look for - I'll delete it later.

Comment: It seems to be built to bring in individual items ("AcquisitionTime"), but not the entire file content.
There is no way to go through each file and select which lines to "SELECT"; I'll have to COPY or INSERT them completely, then rely on queries later to let users select which elements they want.

If I copy the entire xml file I can paste it into a single cell in the column, but just can't get Python or Postgre to do that.

Comment: @user8016440 my xpath query was just to show you that the **entire file** was imported into a single field and that I could query it - AcquisitionTime was just an example. If you have multiple xml elements in a single file, you can import it like I did and later on split it using `UNNEST` - but this might be a totally different issue :)

Comment: If you will eventually be using psycopg2, why start out by debugging what might turn out to be pgadmin-specific issues?

Comment: @JimJones: OK, so maybe it's something in Windows... or this particular machine...

I'll try it on another.

Comment: I didn't start out there, @jjanes: this is where I arrived after trying just about everything else.

Comment: Window file paths do not start with a single forward slash, so '/h:/test.txt' is definitely not a valid path on Windows.  Remove the beginning slash.

Comment: Because I'm not having trouble with Python, or Psycopg2, or even with PostgreSQL, @jjanes.
Because, given the nature of this forum, it seems to make sense to address the problem directly, rather than invite numerous irrelevancies.

Comment: Oh, and without the beginning backslash, Postgre was telling me that the file does not exist.
At least with the backslash it acknowledges the file's existence.

Comment: OK: could import text using PostgreSQL 12 on Windows 7 (previous attempt was with 11 on Windows 10).
Now some problem with the xml code: 


'ERROR:  invalid XML content
DETAIL:  line 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found
<!DOCTYPE mapping SYSTEM "crm_mapping_dtd.dtd">
                                               ^
CONTEXT:  COPY testxml, line 3, column xml: "<!DOCTYPE mapping SYSTEM "crm_mapping_dtd.dtd">"
SQL state: 2200N'

Comment: The xml itself:

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="Text/xsl" href="crm_mapp.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapping SYSTEM "crm_mapping_dtd.dtd">'

Comment: I see what's happening: when it imports text, it inserts a new row after each line break.
The same thing is happening with the xml.

Answer (score 2):

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE xmldata4 (data4 xml);
```

Import using `COPY` ..

```
COPY xmldata4 FROM '/home/jones/user8016440.xml';
```

.. or in an `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO xmldata4(data4) VALUES ('<hotel666> <METADATA> <Tags> <AcquisitionTime>2018-10-09T10:37:18.5268832+02:00</AcquisitionTime> <DetectorState>&lt;CameraState Id=""&gt; &lt;ApplyCameraProfile&gt;false&lt;/ApplyCameraProfile&gt; &lt;/CameraState&gt;</DetectorState> <RoiCenterOffsetX>+000000000000.0000</RoiCenterOffsetX> <RoiCenterOffsetY>+000000000000.0000</RoiCenterOffsetY> </Tags> <DataSchema /> <AttachmentSchema /> </METADATA> </hotel666>');
```

Query xml using `XPATH`:

```
SELECT XPATH('//AcquisitionTime/text()',data4) FROM xmldata4 ;
                xpath                
-------------------------------------
 {2018-10-09T10:37:18.5268832+02:00}
(1 Zeile)
```

Answer (score -2):

SOLUTION:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as xmldata:
  xml_content = xmldata.read()
  postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO xmldata (xfile, data) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
  record_to_insert = (file, xml_content)      
  cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
```